# What Happen If ViewState Disabled

Tags: asp.net, html, viewstate, state, web-applications

I have a large application which Just afew Pages of that uses ViewState.

I want to know whats happen if I Disable ViewState in MasterPages and enable it in pages which really using it.

ViewState Contents are too large in my application and cause to in crease page size. I want to reduce page size with disabling ViewState, Is it a good solution when I reaaly do not use ViewState ?

And , If I disable ViewState, Will my application work as good as when ViewState was Enable ?

Comment: What are you displaying in master page that is taking up ViewState?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I suggested in [your recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305297/what-is-viewstate-how-is-it-encoded-is-it-encrypted-who-uses-viewstate), you should really read this article:

[TRULY understanding ViewState](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx)

(actually, I think every ASP.NET developer should be forced to read and understand that article :-).

Then you will be able to make the correct decision. Also, the time spent reading and understanding the article will be a very good investment for the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable ViewState, and a page needs it, the page will no longer work.