# Completely disabling view state for Web Application

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

I noticed, that even if i disable ViewState at application level (`<pages enableViewState="false"/>`) or at page level (`EnableViewState="false"` in page properties), you can still find hidden field for viewstate in page sources:

```
     <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="NSe2ZpTF4OoGVDqwwtGVO+/liqfw9gUFmsPSD0n169Su3I6VwhG8xgVaSe0iTUfiPp1x0FbW9q47hkfxgDCvxjd2Z9RKo7N+WljNcEezg4Q=" />
```

Why does it still exists in this case? What does ASP.net store in it?

Comment: Look for yourself :-) http://ignatu.co.uk/ViewStateDecoder.aspx (regarding what it stores)

Comment: Do you use master page ? This is probably validation data for your button controls to avoid hacking the page.

Comment: @davidkonrad it says: Couldn't decode the View State. The error was: 'The serialized data is invalid.'

Comment: @Aristos Nope, no master page. I created emtpy web app, then added page from template and dropped single dropdownlist on it.

Comment: Sry. Maybe the viewstate you have above is somehow encrypted after base64? Anyway, It normally works. I am no ASP'er, but have used this tool to see what viewstate contains. Se this for explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/2305310/1407478

Comment: To hide even that last one disable together the validation on the page, but then you left open to the hackers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that since Asp.Net 2.0, the `__VIEWSTATE` hidden field is not only storing `ViewState` but also `ControlState`.

Control state is similar but independent of regular view state. Control state cannot be turned off, so if any control that needs control state is on your page, it will cause the `__VIEWSTATE` hidden field to appear in the rendered markup.

Please see [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more info about control state.